# Iterate through a Python Flask-sqlalchemy Query Result as a list comprehension

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask-sqlalchemy query which returns a list of alert data.

```
alert_data = Alerts.query.filter_by(alertRemediated = False).all()
```

I am iterating through the result with the below code to count all "Critical" alerts.

This code works, but seem inefficient.

```
c = 0
for alert in alert_data:
    if alert.alertSeverity == 'Critical':
        c +=1
total_crit_alerts = c
```

I've tried the following list comprehension to make the code more streamlined, but I cannot get it to work.

```
total_crit_alerts = sum(1 for i in alert_data.alertSevertiy if i == 'Critical')
```

The error returned is:  `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'alertSevertiy'`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pay attention, my friend. In the first case, you're getting the `alertSeverity` field from a single `alert`, while, in your second example, you're trying to get `alertSeverity` of the whole `alert_data`.

Comment: Try this: `sum(1 for alert in alert_data if alert.alertSeverity == 'Critical')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate through alert_data list.
Also you have type in alertSeverity

You can try:

```
total_crit_alerts = sum(1 for i in alert_data if i.alertSeverity == 'Critical')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This is similar to first comment, which works also.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that worked for me, hopefully this helps.

```
# Trying to mock each Alert
from typing import NamedTuple


class Alert(NamedTuple):
    description: str
    alertSeverity: str


# mocking an alert response
alert_data = [
    Alert(f"example alert {idx}", f"Critical" if idx % 2 == 0 else f"Info")
    for idx in range(1, 10)
]

# counting critical alerts
total_crit_alerts = sum(
    1 if alert.alertSeverity == "Critical" else 0 for alert in alert_data
)


print(total_crit_alerts) # should be 4
 

# this should also work
c = 0
for alert in alert_data:
    if alert.alertSeverity == 'Critical':
        c +=1
total_crit_alerts_ = c

print(total_crit_alerts_) # 4
```